# Plugin [id: 'com.google.gms.google-services'] was not found in any of the following sources

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-services

I get **no error** with this version at project gradle:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5'
```

But when I change to **4.3.7**:

```
Plugin [id: 'com.google.gms.google-services'] was not found in any of the following sources:

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.plugins.UnknownPluginException: Plugin [id: 'com.google.gms.google-services'] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (plugin dependency must include a version number for this source)
```

App gradle begins with (error comes from line 4):

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.getkeepsafe.dexcount'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    id 'com.google.firebase.firebase-perf'
    id 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'kotlin-parcelize'
}
```

Project gradle begins with:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.5.0'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-eap' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.7'
        classpath "com.getkeepsafe.dexcount:dexcount-gradle-plugin:2.1.0-RC01"
        classpath "com.google.firebase:perf-plugin:1.4.0"
        classpath "com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.6.1"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
```

At Google maven repository this version exists, but I can't apply it somehow: https://maven.google.com/web/index.html?q=google-services#com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.7

I've tried using latest gradle 6.9, 7.0 and 7.0.1 at gradle-wrapper.properties

Comment: [jar is empty](https://dl.google.com/android/maven2/com/google/gms/google-services/4.3.7/google-services-4.3.7.jar)...

Comment: I think there is some issue with latest `gradle plugin`. I wasted 2 hours today in this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Plugin with id 'com.google.gms.google-services' not found after updated to latest version 4.3.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67531489/plugin-with-id-com-google-gms-google-services-not-found-after-updated-to-lates)

Comment: I guess I'll wait till they upload it to Maven, not Google hosted :) For now will use 4.3.5

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please use version `4.3.8` instead, for context see this [github issue](https://github.com/google/play-services-plugins/issues/178)

Comment: But will it appear on maven repo? https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.gms/google-services?repo=google

Answer (score 1):

use`classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5'` instead of version `4.3.7` it might be the issue with the library

Comment: still using this old version. Just want to be on the latest versions..